# QField operating system

Tags: android, ios, qfield

Does anybody know if Qfield can run on Ipad? My understanding is it was build to run on Android 4.3 or later version. Anybodu knows if it can run on with IOS?

Answer (score 2):

You can try Input, which is based on QGIS and works on both Android and iOS:
https://github.com/lutraconsulting/input

Disclaimer: we develop Input which is free and open source

Answer (score 0):

According to the [project page](https://qfield.org/) and the [documentation](https://qfield.org/docs/installation-guide/index.html), there is no indication that QField exists for any other architecture other than for Android, as Android is the only platform listed for download for the app. Furthermore, the GitHub repository only references build components for Android.